# How open curly brackets in a new line?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

When i use the auto complete, the open bracket “{” remain in the same line of the condition/function/class:

```
if(){

}
```

And i want the open bracket in a new line, like this:

```
if()
{

}
```

How can i configure the Sublime Text to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Install PackageResourceViewer 185 from Package Control
Open the Command Palette
Type PackageResourceViewer - Open Resource
Select C++
Select if-..-(if).sublime-snippet
Move the { character to where you want it
Save the file
```

Don't forget to select the specific language you want to add the changes to. In this case i used c++.

Comment: in my case i am using java. i don't see the `if -..- (if) .sublime-snippet` option even if i'm using c ++. can you check if you see it?